# Is it impossible to mock native jni methods without powermock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, java-native-interface, junit5

I tried to mock native jni methods with may ways but it failed all ways.
How to mock jni methods without powermock?
Is it possible?

** sample code **

```
public class Foo {
    static {
        system.loadLibrary("foo");
    }

    public static native int fooInt();
    public static native void fooVoid(int i);
}

class Bar {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    
    public int fooInt() {
        return foo.fooInt(); // or return Foo.fooInt();
    }
    public void fooVoid() {
        foo.fooVoid(1);
    }
}

class BarTest {
    private static MockedStatic<Foo> fooMockedStatic;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        fooMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Foo.class);
        fooMockedStatic.when(Foo::fooInt).thenReturn(123);
        // No way to mock void method..
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, whatever PowerMock does, you could theoretically do yourself.  That might be a prohibitive amount of work, though.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes. actually it might be possible as you told. But it might be huge work.